# Gstreamer pipeline to play mpegts file works in version 0.10 but not 1.0

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, gst-launch

I have a working gst-launch pipeline in 0.10 :

```
gst-launch-0.10 \
     filesrc location=c:/prog4.mpg \
     ! tsdemux name=dem \
     ! queue \
     ! ac3parse \
     ! a52dec \
     ! audioconvert \
     ! audioresample \
     ! autoaudiosink \
     dem. \
     ! queue \
     ! mpegvideoparse \
     ! mpeg2dec \
     ! autovideosink
```

But same pipeline in version 1.0 spews the error :

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:dem: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
mpegtsbase.c(1639): mpegts_base_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:dem:
stream stopped, reason not-negotiated
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I also tried using playbin, which strangely enough, gives the same error. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** Okay, so I've figured out that the it's the video part that's causing trouble. If I isolate the audio and video parts, the **audio works fine**! It's this bit that's causing trouble:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/rubndsouza/prog4.mpg \
! tsdemux ! queue ! mpegvideoparse ! mpeg2dec ! autovideosink
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is fixed in newer versions of gstreamer.
In my 1.2.3 build I cannot reproduce this at least.

Comment: +1 for taking the effort, but this was ages ago and I don't have the setup anymore to test it. I'll post back here if I get to it though, thanks!